# Apache limit video stream speed

Tags: php, apache, video-streaming

What is the best way to optimize video streaming on CentOS + Apache web server using either a PHP function or Apache module. So in term I want to limit video streaming speed for each visitor to 100kb/s.

Any suggestions what can be used to do this >? If there is a module for streaming can you please refer me to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your videos will show smoothly on such a small speed?

Comment: @zerkms it was just a random number, but I need a method to limit stream speed

Comment: Have you tried to google? Isn't "apache limit bandwidth" the obvious search string for you?

Comment: You want [mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html

Comment: @zerkms maybe google did not work aye? I am well aware of such module in IIS as I use IIS most of the time, Apache is used by a client and he wan't videos streaming speed to be limited. now "stream speed" and "bandwidth speed" don't seem related in any way in my mind, but maybe its just me. I also tried StackExchange and ServerFault for possible material not exactly what I was looking for. This is why I opened a question.